# Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have this cloudformation template :

```
"InstanceProfileProd": {
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
  "Properties": {
    "Path": "/",
    "Roles" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceRole"} ]
  }
},

"CompLayer": {
  "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
  "DependsOn" : "OpsWorksServiceRole",
  "Properties": {
    "AutoAssignElasticIps" : false,
    "AutoAssignPublicIps" : true,
    "CustomJson" : {
      },
      "awscli" : {
        "profils" : {
          "default" : {
            "role_arn": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "InstanceProfileProd","Arn" ] }
          }
        }
      },
    },
    "CustomSecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "SecurityGroupIds" },
    "EnableAutoHealing" : true,
    "InstallUpdatesOnBoot": false,
    "LifecycleEventConfiguration": {
      "ShutdownEventConfiguration": {
        "DelayUntilElbConnectionsDrained": false,
        "ExecutionTimeout": 120 }
      },
      "Name": "Layer",
      "Shortname" : "layer1",
      "StackId": { "Ref": "CompStack" },
  }
},
```

When I validate the template I get this error :

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource InstanceProfileProd
```

The resources are all properly defined and well writen; I don't understand why I am getting this error.
The instance profile is referenced in all the layers of my opsworks stack.

Comment: Beyond the JSON syntax error, if your issue still occurs please post a complete stack template that reproduces the issue, not just a small section of a larger template. To quote the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), "The problem might not be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely."

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not well-formed.

- The line below `CustomJSON` has an extra closing bracket that should be removed:

  ```
  },
  ```
- There is a typo in `profils` that doesn't seem intentional (though probably unrelated to the current error).